# CSS Absolute Positioning - Following Div

Tags: css, position, absolute

I have a banner set up at the top of my site, it has position absolute, so that I can set a height of 100% so that the background image takes up the whole of the screen that the user sees.

I then go to put in another section to be underneath the banner, but instead of the new div showing below the banner, it shows over it at the top of the page.

Hope I've made sense :/

Help!!!

Comment: you will need to post you code.

Comment: If you post your code we can help. Just give an example

Comment: please share your code here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6dhryuxa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using vh for height, and not using absolute positioning. Basically:

```
#banner {
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Legend! Thank you very much! :D

Comment: No Problem! vh (viewport height) is a very useful tool, and it is inherently responsive since it takes in the height of the user's device.

Comment: @Spuddle at least in the JS fiddle from the comment this doesn't change anything (?)

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioned elements don't take any space in the flow of the document. Try relative position instead. Absolute position is rather intended for particular situations.

Here you have an example where I forked your JS fiddle. Have look at the code, especially `height: calc(100% - 100px);` for the height of "banner"

https://jsfiddle.net/hLqmeoww/

Comment: Relative won't let me set height of the div to 100%. Here's the JSFiddle for an example of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/6dhryuxa/

Comment: see my edited answer